# Do I have an SQL Server installed if I see SQL Server programs on control panel?

Tags: installation, sql-server

I'm starting to learn SQL, and want to install a SQL Server.

I have multiple programs of SQL Server installed (I guess they were installed as part of my Visual Studio installation):
[image]
Continued:
[image]

Here's `C:\Program Files` (first folder is ~490MB, second is ~10MB):

[image]

And here's `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` and its sub-directories:

[image]

However, I see no SQL Server program on **Start->All Programs**, I can't find SQL Server Configuration Manager, and the commands `SQLCMD -L` or `OSQL -L` aren't recognised.

So, do I have an SQL Server, and if not, what are all those programs I see in Programs and Features?

EDIT: 
As a beginner, from a learning point of view, what will the installed programs allow me, and what not? From the "Programmbility" table on this (rather old) link, I understand LocalDB almost compares to Express and will have what I need. Is that correct?

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer on all of them, but I know that Microsoft SQL Server Compact is usually packaged with .NET programs that require SQL functionality.

Comment: From the looks of that list, you have the LocalDB and Compact editions installed. You probably want Express Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the [LocalDB entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) (which are a user-space version of the Express versions) all of those entries are for client-side communication to, and management of, an SQL server.

Most of which was probably installed by Visual Studio (as you suspect).

Full versions of MS SQL will have a entry like "Microsoft SQL Server 20XX".

For example, here's a screen shot of Add/Remove Programs on a computer with SQL 2012 Standard installed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit-added question; I also added few more screenshot to supply with more info of what exactly I've got, if needed.

Comment: This answer is still accurate.  What you have installed is for inellisense which uses sql.  If you wanted your own database you need express+